# Wordpress - WP_Query times out

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

estoy teniendo problemas cuando ejecuto WP_Query con más de 5 condiciones en el parámetro tax_query.

Desde una llamada Ajax recibo 6 arrays. Cada uno de estos arrays tienen id's de taxonomias clicadas en un checkbox.

Por ejemplo tengo tengo estas categorías y se clican en el checkbox las que tienen las x.

```
-Tematica
--Privacidad(x)
--Seguridad(x)
-Publicos
--Familias(x)
--Menores
```

El resultado me debería sacar todos los posts que tiene la categoría privacidad O seguridad Y la categoría Familia.

Tengo el siguiente código, el cuál funciona cuando agrego 4 arrays de categorías, si agrego 5 obtengo timeout.

```
'tax_query'         => array(
      'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'material_seg-category',
            'field'     => 'id',
            'terms'     => empty($tematicas)?'%':$tematicas,
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'material_seg-category',
            'field'     => 'id',
            'terms'     => empty($publicos)?'%':$publicos,
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'material_seg-category',
            'field'     => 'id',
            'terms'     => empty($etapas)?'%':$etapas,
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'material_seg-category',
            'field'     => 'id',
            'terms'     => empty($tipos_recursos)?'%':$tipos_recursos,
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'material_seg-category',
            'field'     => 'id',
            'terms'     => empty($fuentes)?'%':$fuentes,
        ),
```

No sé si hay alguna manera de hacer eficiente este código para que no ocurra ese timeout.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Sera que si son 6 categorias quiere traer muchos registros y no termina?

Answer (score 0):

Ya he solucionado esto, lo publico por si alguien le surge este mismo problema.

Al final lo que he hecho no ha sido utilizar una sola consulta si no que he realizado consultas diferentes. Fragmentar la tax_query de manera que cogiera solo array hace que el tiempo de ejecución sea mucho menor.

```
'tax_query'         => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'material_seg-category',
            'field'     => 'id',
            'terms'     => empty($tematicas)?'%':$tematicas,
        ),
```

....

```
'tax_query'         => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'material_seg-category',
            'field'     => 'id',
            'terms'     => empty($publicos)?'%':$publicos,
        ),
```

Luego trabajo todos los loops individualmente, comparándolos y consiguiendo un único array con los ID's comunes a todos ellos.